How to search and report on a network drive to specify if its file or a folder
I run the following script to get the .csv list of all folders and files in the network directory.  Can someone please assist to amend the script to include a separate column in the csv to specify if the item is a folder or a file?
$Directory ="X:\Sub\General"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force | ForEach {[PSCustomObject]@{
FullPath = $_.FullName  
FileName = $_.Name
Size = $_.Length
Extension = $_.Extension
Creation = $_.CreationTime
LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
}
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\users\abc\Downloads\fulllist.csv"

Thank you
My PS script knowledge is very limited so I am not sure how to amend the code.

As an alternative to Anthony's helpful solution, consider using Select-String with a calculated property.

You can use PSIsContainer and the modified script is below. There will be an new column "Is folder" in the generated CSV file and it will contain True if it is folder otherwise False.
$Directory ="X:\Sub\General"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force | ForEach {[PSCustomObject]@{
FullPath = $_.FullName  
FileName = $_.Name
Size = $_.Length
Extension = $_.Extension
Creation = $_.CreationTime
LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
IsFolder = $_.PSIsContainer
}
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\users\abc\Downloads\fulllist.csv"


resulting CSV listing
Thanks @Iit updated the script.
\\?\ directive can be used to read longer paths in PS
Updated script to handle long paths
$Directory = "\\?\X:\Sub\General"  
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FullPath = $_.FullName
        FileName = $_.Name
        Size = $_.Length
        Extension = $_.Extension
        Creation = $_.CreationTime
        LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
        IsFolder = $_.PSIsContainer
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\users\abc\Downloads\fulllist.csv" 


Hi All,  I have a new issue where I am getting ' Could not find part of the path' error.  I googled and found that the error happens if the path length is over 256 characters.  Could you please assist to include everything irrespective of the character length.  Thank you

@DineshPadmanabhan updated script to handle longer paths. please give it a try. thank you.
